# Java project from gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm beginner in the theme, but I have a question: can I transform a gradle project to Java project? I have a gradle multi project, and I would like to create java project, because I would like to create from Java project, a jar file.
Could someone explain me step by step? Thx. :)

Comment: Do you know how to create a JAR file manually without Gradle or IDE?  I'd make sure I could do that first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great tutorial on how to build a jar using gradle: http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Answer (score 1):

**As i see the problem is the following:**

There is a **gradle multi-project**,with gradle specified files (like build.gradle, common.gradle, ...). 
The task is to import this multi-project to eclipse, but not as a gradle project (using gradle IDE)
**It should appeare in Eclipse** Kepler **as a java project** without any errors! Its therefore we want to compile, develop it, and of course make jar file from it, that we can use it in the future as other projects dependencies...

Import as an existing source java project doesnt worked at all. Eclipse couldn't recognise it as a project.

Our multi-project looks like:

```
[root folder] 

   \1.project
      \sub projects
          \build.gradle

       gradle files(common, build, libraries, settings)

   \2.project
       \sub projects
           \build.gradle

       gradle files(common, build, libraries, settings)


  Thanks for any help!
```